# Error in packaging and deploying the pyspark application to cluster via spark-submit

Tags: pyspark, spark-submit

I have code structure like below:-

```
my_app
    |
    |--- common
    |   |
    |   |---init.py
    |   |---spark
    |       |--init.py
    |    
    |   
    |--- subproject1
    |   |    
    |   |-- init.py
    |   |-- main.py
    |   |--job
    |       |
    |       |--myjob.py
    |       |--init.py
    |---setup.py
```

So, the entry point of my application is subproject1--> main.py. The my_app has two modules - common and subproject1.
Basically what I want to do is submit something like below to my spark cluster

> spark-submit --py-files jobs.egg main.py

But when I am submitting I am getting 2 issues:-

1. first of all the main.py is under a subproject inside the my_app.
2. import error from the main.py when I a, trying to import common module.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is the error are you exactly facing?